# Persist IEnumerable<T> after server side validation ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using server-side validation as described [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation#server-side-validation). In the OnGet method for the page I'm populating an IEnumerable with a list of items from the database.

```
    [BindProperty]
    public IEnumerable<Status> Statuses { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        Statuses = await _service.GetStatuses();
        return Page();
    }
```

When the ModelState.IsValid returns false the page is redisplayed but the content of the IEnumerable is now zero items.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new PageResult();
        }
        ... Save to DB
 }
```

Is there an easy way to persist the IEnumerable< Status>, if I replicate the Statues = await _service.GetStatues(); before return Page(); it works, but that requires another trip to the database so I'd like to avoid if possible. Does there need to be a hidden field in the View to store the full list of IEnumerable< Status>?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try "TempData" ? @RaKer

Comment: @WaleedNaveed Yes, I have tried adding the list to Tempdata but the page then just returns HTTP 500, but setting a breakpoint on the return Page(); line I can see that the Tempdata has been updated - am I missing something else?

Comment: Can you share the code @RaKer

Comment: @WaleedNaveed, the code is like this

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        Statuses = await _service.GetStatuses();
        TempData["Statuses"] = Statuses;
        TempData.Keep("Statuses");
        return Page();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried adding the list to Tempdata but the page then just
> returns HTTP 500,

This error indicates that you should have stored Statuses directly in TempData.

In fact, when we pass object data, **we need to serialize it to json format, then store it in TempData, and then get it through deserialization**.

Try following code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
   
   [BindProperty]
    public IEnumerable<Status> Statuses { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        Statuses = await _service.GetStatuses();
        TempData["Statuses"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Statuses);
        return Page();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Statuses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Status>>(TempData["Statuses"].ToString());
            return new PageResult();
        }
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Comment: that's perfect, does does what I was looking for.  Thanks for the explanation of needing to serialize data that is stored in TempData.